# Error while accessing json array stored in MySQL DB

Tags: javascript, node.js

In one of my sql table's row there's a column stores JSON array. I can retrieve it via node JS but when I try to do json array stuff I get errors all the time. My Json array is as follows in sql DB.

```
{ characters: [{ code: "45", col: "", rem: "" },{ code: "", col: "", rem: "" },{ code: "", col: "", rem: "" },{ code: "", col: "", rem: "" }]}
```

I tried like this after getting via async functions

`console.log(result[0].init_characters)`

Sure data shows. But when I try to do,

`console.log(result[0].init_characters.characters[1].code)`

it gives errors like '1' is not defined.
How can I get 1st arrays 'code' which is '45'?

Tried several methods like below. STill no luck

```
const myJSON = JSON.stringify(tt); 
const obj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
console.log(obj.characters[1].code);
```

Still no luck

Edit:Code that retrievs data

> await connection.query(
> charSessSearch_query,
> async (err, result) => {
> if (err) throw err;
> console.log("------> done Results 1");
> console.log(result.length);
> var tt = result[0].init_characters;
> const myJSON = JSON.stringify(tt);
> const obj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
> )

Yes this is mysql

Comment: Hi there. You should add the code that retrieves data. Also try logging the results of retrieval that'll help you understand issue better.

Comment: can you share the actual `result` data or `result[0].init_characters` response? and to get 45 it would be `characters[0].code`

Comment: @Omkar76 when result or result[0].init_characters is console logged it shows the array. But when result[0].init_characters..characters[1].code it says undefined

Comment: 1/ Provided string with `{ characters: ...` is not valid JSON - Make sure you quote the keys
2/ The provided string is converted again with JSON.stringify into yet another string
3/ Finally you should parse it again but it's string again (not JSON object)

Comment: @vladaman 1. as suggested in 1st answer i've fixed it like this {"characters":[{"code":"45","col":"","rem":""},{"code":"","col":"","rem":""},{"code":"","col":"","rem":""},{"code":"","col":"","rem":""}]}
But after that I don't get to convert it to json object. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I want to let you know about 2 things.

- Correctly, the json array should be like this in the sql db.
  now the format is a bit wrong I think.

`{"characters":[{"code":"45","col":"","rem":""},{"code":"","col":"","rem":""},{"code":"","col":"","rem":""},{"code":"","col":"","rem":""}]}`

- And to get "45" as you want, the index should be "0" not "1"!

hope this would be helpful to you.

Comment: if it still doesn't work, please try to put the index to variable and use that instead.

ex: `const index = 0; console.log(obj.characters[index].code);`

Comment: When i run as that it shows following error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

Comment: @Cutting_edge, can you show me the log for result[0].init_characters.characters please?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Query.<anonymous> (<location>.js:449:54)
    at Query.<anonymous> (<location>\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (D<location>\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Sequence.end (<location>\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (<location>node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (<location>\node_ ......

Node.js v18.15.0

Comment: @Cutting_edge, let's keep your code then.

`I tried like this after getting via async functions
console.log(result[0].init_characters)
Sure data shows. But when I try to do,
console.log(result[0].init_characters.characters[1].code)
it gives errors like '1' is not defined.`

it means, the array is empty when you console log, but filled later.
so maybe, if you try `console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0].init_characters))`, it won't show as you expected. could you have a check please?

you need to await for the result and operate with them when it's ready exactly.

Comment: Ok I;m sorry for the hassle, finally found the error. I removed stringify then use array as you told. Problem solves. Thanks Everyone